# How is an object of type BaseModelOutput in huggingface transformer library subscriptable?

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I have a code where self.encoder is an object of type ViTEncoder. ViTEncoder's [forward](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/v4.26.1/src/transformers/models/vit/modeling_vit.py#L371) method returns an object of type BaseModelOutput.

When I call the forward method of ViTEncoder, I get back an object that is subscriptable, how is this possible?

```
# self.encoder defined in the init method of class ViTModel
self.encoder = ViTEncoder(config)
```

```
# code snippet in the forward method of class ViTModel
encoder_outputs = self.encoder(
            embedding_output,
            head_mask=head_mask,
            output_attentions=output_attentions,
            output_hidden_states=output_hidden_states,
            return_dict=return_dict,
        )
sequence_output = encoder_outputs[0] # how is this subscriptable?
print(f"The encoder output is {encoder_outputs}") # prints the type of object as BaseModelOutput
```

This is the definition of [BaseModelOutput](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/ae54e3c3b18bac0832ad62ea9b896dfd52a09850/src/transformers/modeling_outputs.py#L24-L46) class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [BaseModelOutput](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/ae54e3c3b18bac0832ad62ea9b896dfd52a09850/src/transformers/modeling_outputs.py#L24-L46) class inherits from [ModelOutput](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/ae54e3c3b18bac0832ad62ea9b896dfd52a09850/src/transformers/utils/generic.py#L208) which implements [_*getitem*_](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__):

```py
from typing import List
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class X():
  bla:List[str] =None
  def __getitem__(self, i:int):
    return self.bla[i]

x = X(["tldr", "no", "yes"])
print(x[1])
```

Output:

```
no
```